# Rename "tarantino" to "quentin-tarantino"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

For the sake of consistency and to avoid duplicates, the tag [tarantino](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tarantino) needs to be renamed to [quentin-tarantino](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quentin-tarantino) with the former possibly being added as a synonym of the latter. This is how it is with [alfred-hitchcock](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alfred-hitchcock) and [hitchcock](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitchcock).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would agree - more information is better than less.

To ease confusion however I've created a tag synonym too - from tarantino to quentin-tarantino.